# How to split a [String] into rows?

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift

I'm using a `UITextView` to add some values into an array.

I'd like to separate the text from the `UITextView` into single items if they have a newline (`\n`) or a comma (`,`) between them.

```
var values = self.textLabel.text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
for item in values {
    if item != "" {
        cellDataSet.insert([item, false], atIndex: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to separate a `String` on multiple [tokens](http://techterms.com/definition/token), use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(_:)`

Example:

```
let text = "This is, some, text; With multiple | seperators"
let separators = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ",;|")
let values = text.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(separators)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the globally available `split` function to do the same.

```
let stringToSplit = "Words,Separated\nBy,Comma,Or\nNewline"
let outputArray = split(stringToSplit) {$0 == "," || $0 == "\n"}
```